# How to ensure groups of radio buttons do not deselect each other in HTML?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I face a problem to show the Question and Options on view page and submit the result to the result page and check the result is true or false. The code is below.

The problem is the radio button allowed only one to be checked. See my screenshot below. How can I fix this?

[image: Exam process]

[TakeExam.jsp]

```
<form  method="post"  action="Examprocess" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-1" style="color: white"> Subject:</label>    
         <div class="col-sm-3">
         <select class="form-control" name="sub">
         <option>Select your choice</option>
        <option>cprog</option>
        <option>cpp</option>
        <option>html</option>
        <option>java</option>  
         </select>
         </div>
         </div>
    <div class="form-group">   
         <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
       <input style="color:red" type="submit"  value="start exam" />
       </div>
       </div>
  </form>
```

[Examprocess (Servlet)]

```
package exam.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import exam.DAO.CTest;


@WebServlet("/Examprocess")
public class Examprocess extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String subject = request.getParameter("sub");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session .setAttribute("Subject", subject);
        if(subject.equals("cprog")) {

            CTest ctest = new CTest();
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("examq", ctest.getdata());
            rd.forward(request, response);

            //response.sendRedirect("view.jsp");
        }
        else if(subject.equals("cpp")) {

            response.sendRedirect("view1.jsp");

        }

    }

}
```

[CTest.java]

```
package exam.DAO;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import exam.DTO.ExamQ;
import exam.utilities.ConnectionFac;

public class CTest {

    Connection cn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ConnectionFac con = new ConnectionFac();
    String selectctest ="select * from ctest";

    public ArrayList<ExamQ> getdata() {

        ArrayList<ExamQ> arr =new ArrayList<ExamQ>();


        try {
            rs=con.getResultSet(selectctest);
            while(rs.next()) {
                ExamQ examques =new ExamQ();
                examques.setQid(rs.getShort(1));
                examques.setQuestion(rs.getString(2));
                examques.setOption1(rs.getString(3));
                examques.setOption2(rs.getString(4));
                examques.setOption3(rs.getString(5));
                examques.setOption4(rs.getString(6));
                examques.setAnswer(rs.getString(7));
                arr.add(examques);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arr;
    }



}
```

[ExamQ.java (getter and Setter)]

```
package exam.DTO;

public class ExamQ {
    int qid;
    String question;
    String option1;
    String option2;
    String option3;
    String option4;
    String answer;

    public int getQid() {
        return qid;
    }
    public void setQid(int qid) {
        this.qid = qid;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getOption1() {
        return option1;
    }
    public void setOption1(String option1) {
        this.option1 = option1;
    }
    public String getOption2() {
        return option2;
    }
    public void setOption2(String option2) {
        this.option2 = option2;
    }
    public String getOption3() {
        return option3;
    }
    public void setOption3(String option3) {
        this.option3 = option3;
    }
    public String getOption4() {
        return option4;
    }
    public void setOption4(String option4) {
        this.option4 = option4;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ExamQ))
            return false;
        ExamQ other = (ExamQ) obj;
        if (answer == null) {
            if (other.answer != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!answer.equals(other.answer))
            return false;
        if (option1 == null) {
            if (other.option1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!option1.equals(other.option1))
            return false;
        if (option2 == null) {
            if (other.option2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!option2.equals(other.option2))
            return false;
        if (option3 == null) {
            if (other.option3 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!option3.equals(other.option3))
            return false;
        if (option4 == null) {
            if (other.option4 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!option4.equals(other.option4))
            return false;
        if (qid != other.qid)
            return false;
        if (question == null) {
            if (other.question != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!question.equals(other.question))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

[view.jsp]

```
<div class="row">
   <div  class="col-sm-4" >
   </div>
  <div  class="col-sm-8" >

   <form method="post" action="result.jsp">

   <% int i=1; %>

<c:forEach items="${examq}" var="examq" >
  <label style="color:white">Q<%=i %>:<c:out value="${examq.getQuestion() }"></c:out></label><br>

  <label style="color:white" for="O1">O1:<c:out value="${examq.getOption1() }"></c:out></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="${examq.getOption1() }"><br>

  <label style="color:white" for="O2">O2:<c:out value="${examq.getOption2() }"></c:out></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="${examq.getOption2() }" ><br>

  <label style="color:white" for="O3">O3:<c:out value="${examq.getOption3() }"></c:out></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="${examq.getOption3() }"><br>

  <label style="color:white" for="O4">O4:<c:out value="${examq.getOption3() }"></c:out></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="${examq.getOption3() }"><br>  

  <hr>         
    </c:forEach> 


    <input type="submit" value="submit">

 </form>

  <a href="takeexam.jsp">GoBack</a>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of a screenshot

Comment: I've rolled this back to the first question state in order to help get it reopened. I have renamed the title to clarify the problem. For your additional question Raju, please ask a brand new question. It is in your interests to avoid on-hold questions, since too many of these will apply an automatic question ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the radio groups in your HTML form have conflicting names. You're using the following for all groups:

```
name="radio"
```

What you need to do is to use a different name for each group; in order words, use the same name for each question within a single group. Assuming your question IDs are integers, you could do something like:

```
name="radio_${examq.getQid()}"
```

That will ensure that each group exhibits mutually exclusive selection characteristics independently of the other groups.

Comment: now its work correctly thank you for solution.But now I have another problem. Can you resolve this also? ** codes are posted above**

Comment: You are welcome. See my remarks under the question.

Comment: how can i check the answer is correct and give marks on them .The marks are shows on the result.jsp page Please #halfer  give me a solution. please

Comment: This is a new question @Raju, so please ask a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stack Overflow can't allow me to ask  the  next question right now.

Comment: My guess is that your new question will need a great deal more explanation. Nevertheless, I will see if I can speed up the reopening of this question, so that Stack Overflow will allow you to ask a new question sooner.

Comment: I am concerned that your new question will be too broad, and if that gets downvotes or close votes, you will have an even harder time of asking a question after that. "How to check the answer is correct" is essentially your whole application, isn't it? I am not going to get into answering it here (not enough space) but I would advise you to ask a more specific question when you are allowed to post.

Comment: Halfer i post a new question please solve the problem.Thank you